# regex allow only numbers or empty string

Tags: regex

Can someone help me create this regex. I need it to check to see if the string is either entirely whitespace(empty) or if it only contains positive whole numbers. If anything else it fails. This is what I have so far.

```
/^\s*|[0-9][0-9]*/
```

Comment: [0-9][0-9]* is the same as [0-9]+

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
/^(\s*|\d+)$/
```

If you want a positive number without leading zeros, use `[1-9][0-9]*`

If you don't care about whitespaces *around* the number, you can also try:

```
/^\s*\d*\s*$/
```

Note that you don't want to allow partial matching, for example **`123`**`abc`, so you need the start and end anchors: `^...$`.
Your regex has a common mistake: `^\s*|\d+$`, for example, does not enforce a whole match, as is it the same as `(^\s*)|(\d+$)`, reading, Spaces at the start, or digits at the end.

Comment: your second example will only match whitespace if it's at the beginning or end ... it wouldn't match "1 2 3"

Comment: @Cfreak, why would you want to match `1 2 3`

Comment: I read it as whitespace or whole numbers. As in whitespace in the string doesn't matter

Comment: That's cool. It's possible the OP wants to ignore all spaces. That's why you got my +1 - your answer is shorter. Also, the OP said "positive whole number **s** "

Comment: Well, I suppose `^\s*([1-9]\d*\s*)+$` allows only spaces and positive numbers, but I'm just being silly.

Comment: In Javascript, this isn't working; it's reporting a string 'abc' to be true (using `test()`)

Comment: @dclowd9901 - Not sure what it the problem: `/^\s*\d*\s*$/.test("abc") === false`. Maybe you left out the anchors?

Comment: @Kobi: was able to get it to work with that variant, but not the `^(\s*|\d+)$` variant.

Answer (score 20):

To match a number or empty string ''  i.e the user has not entered any input do this

```
(^[0-9]+$|^$)
```

To match a number, an empty string, or a white space character

```
(^[0-9]+$|^$|^\s$)
```

Test this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Kobi has a good answer but technically you don't have to capture it (unless you're going to do something the output)

```
/^[\s\d]+$/
```

Or if you don't care if the string is completely empty (i.e. "")

```
/^[\s\d]*$/
```

To clarify I understood the original question to mean whitespace in the string should be ignored.

Comment: The problem with `/^[\s\d]*$/` is it matches things like `123 123`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the group in Kobi's answer isn't for capturing the number, rather it's to keep the anchors (`^` and `$`) away from `|`

Answer (score 2):

You can try it-

```
/^\d*$/
```

To match with white space-

```
/^[\s\d\s]*$/
```

Comment: that doesn't match whitespace

Answer (score 2):

This helped me. It matches empty string and any number you enter.

```
/^(|\d)+$/
```

Try here if you want: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+([\.\,][0]{2})?$
```

I found this worked for me. Allow any whole number, but only a decimal of .00

Pass

- 999 90
- 100
- 100.00
- 101.00
- 1000.00

Fails

- 101.01
- 1000.99

Try it at http://regexpal.com/