# Regular expression not match

Tags: html, regex, asp.net-mvc

in a html page with a form, I have this two fields:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HouseNumberSuffix)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
```

And in the model of this page this fields have the following regular expression

```
 [RegularExpression("[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]*",
 ErrorMessage = "At least one digit is required for this field")]
  public string HouseNumberSuffix { get; set; }

 [RegularExpression("[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

So when I'm trying to submit the form, the above fields are invalid, even I don't write anything inside of their textbox. I want to modify the regular expression to accept also empty string. Until now I've tried:
[regex allow only numbers or empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248909/regex-allow-only-numbers-or-empty-string) ,
[Regex, Number or Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957119/regex-number-or-empty) 
Thanks !

Comment: The plus requires at least **one** character, so changing it to `[A-Za-z0-9]*` would help for the first and `[0-9]*` for the second. However, this way, the first would also allow only letters. You might also want to anchor the strings with `^` and `$`, respectively.

Comment: @Jan why don't you write this as an answer; it's what I'd say if I were writing an answer

Comment: @SpoonMeiser: Done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus requires at least **one** character, so changing it to `[A-Za-z0-9]*` would help for the first and `[0-9]*` for the second. However, this way, the first would also allow only letters. You might also want to anchor the strings with `^` and `$`, respectively.

---

As @Simon pointed out, this does not really answer your question, so for the first the following expression will work:

```
(?:(?=^$)|(?=^\D*\d))^\w*$
# either an empty string
# or at least one digit in the lookaheads
# afterwards only digits and letters are allowed
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gF4tA4/1).

Comment: You lose this condition "At least one digit is required for this field" by doing that. [A-Za-z0-9]* match "" (nothing) but also "abc" (no digit)

Comment: @SimonPA: That's exactly what is written in my answer: **However, this way, the first would also allow only letters.**

Answer (score 1):

Matching 0 or 1 time your pattern:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]*)?

([0-9]+)?
```

`( )` for grouping your expression logic and
`?` for 0 or 1